# Illustrator: undo/redo for zooming

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Let's say I have View 1 as shown below.

Now, I zoom into part of View 1 and then arrive to View 2.

I am doing some fine editing and then I want to go back to exactly View 1.

Then I notice that I still need some fine editing so I want to go back exactly to View 2.

Is there a shortcut/command for switching between View 1 and View 2 ?

Sort of like an undo/redo zoom functionality ?

I am not talking about the New View/Edit Views functionality, I am looking for something simpler and quicker than that.

View 1 before zooming:

[image]

View 2 after zooming in to a portion of View 1:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the `View > New View...` Menu item, no there is not. You may find the **Navigator Panel** helpful though.

You can also open an additional window for a document (`Window > New Window`) which will allow you to zoom in on one window and see the zoomed out view in the other. Changes will be reflected in both windows.

Comment: Good to know  ! Thanks, perhaps I can open up two windows, one has one view and the other has the other view.

Comment: @jhegedus I actually added that while you were commenting :)

Comment: Wrote the edits at the same time :)